# How do I connect the other machine from inside of docker container at windows?

Tags: docker

Now I put a streaming media server in the container. This streaming media server needs to pull the video stream from the external camera (use RTSP protocol, port 554), but it doesn't work with the camera in the internal network environment of docker.

Host IP: 192.168.1.xxx, gateway: 192.168.1.254
Camera IP: 192.168.0.xxx

I know how to use `network_ mode: "host"` can let the container and host share the network, but it can't be used under windows.

It seems to work in theory, but in practice it is uncertain.